# Как проверить переменную на тип str в Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, переменные, типы-данных

> **Задача:**
>
> Проверить переменную на принадлежность к типу *string* на языке программирования *Python 3*

Привет всем. В процессе написания программы на `Python 3` потребовалось проверить переменную на тип `str` (то есть узнать, принадлежит ли переменная типу `string`)
Пробовал конструкцию `try - except`, но в данном случае ошибки не происходит, не смотря на то, что переменная может являтся любого типа (ну или почти любого). Пробовал также вот такое условие:

```
if type(*имя переменной*) != <class 'str'> : :
```

Но из этого тоже ничего не выходит. Выдает ошибку:

```
if type(*имя переменной*) != <class 'str'> :
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**Вопросы:**

1. В чем ошибка и можно ли её устранить?
2. Если нет, то какие существуют способы решения задачи?
3. Можно ли осуществлять такую проверку на другие типы переменных?

**P.S.** Заранее извиняюсь, если этот вопрос дубликат. В таком случаее попрощу дать ссылки на ответы, сам вопрос могу **удалить** (если ответы решат мою проблему)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Просто используйте специально предназначенную для этого [функцию](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance)

```
if isinstance(имя_переменной, str):
    print('Да, это строка')
```

Comment: я думаю было бы полезным привести пример проверки сразу на несколько типов: `isinstance('string', (str, bytes))` ...

Answer (score 6):

Ещё вариант:

```
a="aaaaa"
if(type(a)==str):
    print ("Это строка")
```

Comment: Спасибо, Ваш ответ был тоже полезен (просто не могу 2 ответа принять))